# (JS/HTML) How do I pull an MP3 from the local directory and assign it to an audio element?

Tags: javascript, audio

I am part of a team building a basic audio visualizer and I am in charge of the functions. I have an input button coded as "input id="audioFile" type="file" accept="audio/*" which opens the computer's directory and allows you to select a file. My question is how can I assign the selected file to an audio element such that I can manipulate it with other functions?

Comment: @TechnicalChaos write it as an answer

Comment: Too late i already had, but thanks. Thought I'd clicked on the answer box :)

Answer (score 1):

Untested stuff here, but a brief overview. 
You need to do this in a couple of steps. 
Add a callback to your file:

```
document.getElementById('audioFile').addEventListener('change', changeMusic, false);
```

And then make a function with that name `changeMusic` that gets the file name:

```
function changeMusic(evt) {
    var file = evt.target.files;
    file = file[0]; 
    // get the first element in list of filenames 

    var filename = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    // createObjectUrl gets the files location and makes it a path.

    document.getElementById('the_audio_player').src = filename;
    // change source of audio
}
```

edit: couple of typos.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Sorry but I have an additional question about the code you wrote. As I am new to JS, I am not sure what value to include for the "evt" parameter when assigning the function to the input button (as in onclick = "changeMusic(???);"). I looked around and the evt seems to have some kind of quasi boolean functionality, however I am not sure specifically how to implement this. My continued thanks for any thoughts on the matter.

Comment: In this example, you're not assigning a click. You are assigning a change. The `addEventListener('change', changeMusic, false);` Creates a DOM event that is passed into the function as evt (an arbritrary name). In our case, this event contains a list of attributes from the file-picker - so we get the function to use `evt.target.files` to get the list of files selected (1 file still comes through as a list from the browser). Hope that helps a little. Tl;dr: evt (or 'e') is a built in list of stuff that the target has already. You don't pass it in the same as a normal function.